# Converting Group By and Count from Java to C#

Tags: c#, linq

I stumbled across something that surely is a newbie problem for an experienced C# programmer (I come from a Java background). Imagine the following Java POJO:

```
public class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    Person(final String firstName, final String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

If I have a `List<Person>` and want to *group by* the last name and then count the number of values for each last name I would do something like this in Java:

```
final List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("John", "Doe"),
        new Person("Jim", "Doe"),
        new Person("Johnny", "Puma"));

final Map<String, Long> map =
        people.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Person::getLastName,
                        Collectors.counting()));
```

The map would then contain:

> {Doe=2, Puma=1}

How would I go about doing the grouping in C#? What I have tried so far is:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And then the grouping:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = new Person[]
{
    new Person {FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"},
    new Person {FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Doe"},
    new Person {FirstName = "Johnny", LastName = "Puma"}
};

// This is what could surely be improved
var map = people.GroupBy(p => p.LastName)                
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

This works the same way as in the Java case. But, is this the *C#-way* of doing things or are there other preferred solutions/styles?

Coming from the Java eco system I've had no previous experience with C# and I simply try to *get it right* from the beginning so please forgive me if this question is to trivial or needs clarification.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it; it's clear and concise.

Comment: You should tag/highlight the technologies you expect in your answer, rather than ones which you can already search on in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Actually depends how you intend to use those values. In you case you will need to iterate in that dictionary to get those results so you can skip that aditional part.

In the below case you can just skip your last part (call for Dictionary):

```
    var group = people.GroupBy(p => p.LastName);

    foreach(var p in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Key + " " + p.Count());
    }
```

Will print:

> Doe 2
>
> Puma 1

Test on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fg9CyO)

The `Key` will always be the property you chose in the `GroupBy` and the who has grouped will be available by iterating in that `group` variable. In my case I just `Count()` like you did.